# Android Studio emulator will not open the chrome browser

Tags: android-studio, google-chrome, android-emulator

##### System info:

> Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
> Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
> VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
> Linux 5.4.199-1-manjaro

##### Issue:

If I try to open the Chrome browser in Android Studio's emulator, when I get to the "Turn on sync?" screen, if I tap "No thanks" or "Yes, I'm in" the emulator completely locks up. I'm unable to swipe and close Chrome browser or do anything. I can only crash the emulator. Then I "wipe data" and try again.

Anyone know how to get past this so I can open the Chrome browser in the emulator? Webviewer works just fine, but opening Chrome directly in the emulator does not.

I've tried different SDK's, but at this point I cannot find a remedy for this odd issue.

##### Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Encountered this as well, both canary and stable (chipmunk) is acting up. I even updated the Android System WebView from 91 -> 104 and still the same

Answer (score 1):

Running the emulator with the -feature -Vulkan worked for me. You will need [android emulator cli](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) installed.

To see your avd devices enabled run: emulator -list-avds

In my case, I'm using Pixel 6, so i runned: emulator @Pixel_6 -feature -Vulkan

Worked like a charm.

PS: I actually got the answer from the author's [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236946818?pli=1) at IssueTracker. Just posting this here to help others with same problem.

Comment: wow - struggling with this for months, only found this solution now and it works like a charm! THANKS! -> `my_sdk_folder/android/emulator$ ./emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_30 -feature -Vulkan` on kubuntu 22.04, AMD Ryzen